# How to pass mutable objects by value to java

Tags: java

Is there any way that I can pass mutable Objects by value to a function in java?

What I actually want is to pass an object to a method, do some operations on it (change it) and again call that method with that old object only(not the changed value).

here is some sample:

```
    { MyObj obj = new MyObj(); obj.setName("name");

    append(obj); 
    System.out.println(obj.name);

    prepend(obj); 
    System.out.println(obj.name);

    }

    void append(MyObj obj){ obj.name+="1"; }

    void prepend(MyObj obj){ String a = "1"; obj.name=a+obj.name; }
```

At the end of this code, I want output as:

```
name1
1name
```

Comment: You'll only get that output if the object *is* mutated, won't you? How are you expecting anything to know that you want to ignore the appended "1" *only after the first call to `println`*?

Comment: thats what I want to know. How can I do that?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Objects themselves aren't passed at all in Java. Ever.

But *everything* is passed by value - where the only things that can be passed are primitive values and references.

It's not quite clear what you're trying to do - is the idea that you'd like to have a method with (say) a `StringBuilder` parameter, but without any changes made to the object from within the method being visible to the caller? If so, you basically need to clone the object yourself.

Comment: Absolutely correct, but I didn't point it out myself because I figured the OP wouldn't find it useful. :) Which is actually kind of unlike me. ;)

Comment: @Karl: Understanding the object model (and that if you have a variable of some reference type, the value of that variable is a reference, not an object) is absolutely core to getting around in Java, IMO. I'm very picky on this topic :)

Comment: Jon Skeet has no vote yet? Weird! :) (2 minutes later...) nevermind...he got one! :)

Comment: That's the bystander effect, of course. Everyone expects someone else to upvote, because it's Jon Skeet ;)

Comment: @Karl Knechtel, Jon Skeet gets upvote by the mere fact of opening aN SO question which he has answered. :-)

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately, no. Java **never** passes Objects by value, it passes the *reference* of the object by value.

Explanation from [here](http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?JavaDoesntPassByValue):

> What's really happening is that
>   objects are always held by reference
>   in java -- never by value -- and the
>   references are, indeed, being passed
>   by value.

Comment: Java never passes objects, full stop. It passes references, by value. Don't contradict your own quote. ;) It does make a difference; if it were really passing the objects by reference, you could implement the equivalent of `std::swap` in C++.

Answer (score 1):

Why do you need to do this? If you don't change the object, then it doesn't matter. If you do change the object, and don't want to affect the caller's object, then just **make a copy** locally. But I would guess that at least 90% of the time people think they need to do that, they really don't.

Show some code. What are you **really** trying to do?

Comment: yes, i want to change the object inside the method and dont want the change to be reflected outside. How do you make a copy? Even that copy will be a copy of reference of the object?

Comment: A copy, in the sense of "a completely new object that represents the same value as the original". How you make it depends on your class definition. This is something you have to think about and implement (it isn't hard). Once you have an implementation, you can make it into a member function called `clone()`, and claim to implement the `Clonable` interface.

Comment: `Cloneable` cant be implemented for all the objects since its defined as protected in the `Object` class. we need to override it in our class and if the class is a java library class then that also becomes impossible.

Comment: What are the classes you are needing a copy of? You don't need to make it Cloneable, just make a deep-copy manually i.e. with getters and setters: clone.setFooBar(otherObject.getFooBar())

Answer (score -2):

AFAIK immutable/mutable is not related with passing by value/reference. Strings are passed by reference, not value. What makes string immutable is design of string class itself.
Perhaps you may explain a bit more what you looking for.

Comment: See other comments about the distinction between passing a value by reference and passing a reference by value.

Comment: YEah I'm missing word copy - reference copy. What makes this question important to me is question about object beeing immunable.

Comment: It's immutable, not immunable.